# Move data from one sheet into a fifo table on another sheet based on actual month using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm rather new in VBA and could really need some VBA help..
I'm trying to automate a "Score card" that I use for rating performances on team members at work.
Its a list of 20 names and each person is rated at 8 different parameters. I Sort the list afterwards by vba and this works fine.

My problem is, that after rating all members and the list is sorted (Sheet1) (highest to lowest), i would like to export the name and their score to a different sheet (Sheet2)". The list I want to export would be nice to come in the column for the month that I export the data. If I export data in august it should fill in for the column August. When a new year starts data should be filled in and overwrite January and so on.

Note that the names on the "input list" can be in different positions every month depending on their monthly score.

Names are in range "B5:B29" The score is "J5:J25" and Average score is L5:L25

I would really appreciate some inputs here.

If anyone has a working code for something similar, I would really appreciate it. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A VBA Lookup: First Column, Then Rows

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateScoreCard()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Update Score Card"
    Const NAME_NOT_FOUND As String = "Not found"
    Const DEBUG_PRINT As Boolean = True
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Input List")
    Dim sMonth As String: sMonth = CStr(sws.Range("B3").Value) ' Month (string)
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = sws _
        .Range("B6", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)) ' Lookup (column)
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns("J") ' Return (column)
    
    If DEBUG_PRINT Then
        Debug.Print sMonth, slrg.Address(0, 0), srrg.Address(0, 0)
    End If
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Score Card")
    Dim dmrg As Range: Set dmrg = dws.Range("B3").Resize(, 12) ' Months (row)
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = dws _
        .Range("A4", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) ' Lookup (column)
    
    Dim dcIndex As Variant: dcIndex = Application.Match(sMonth, dmrg, 0)
    If IsError(dcIndex) Then ' month not found
        MsgBox "Month """ & sMonth & """ not found.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    'Else ' month found; do nothing
    End If
    
    Dim drrg As Range: Set drrg = dlrg.EntireRow _
        .Columns(dmrg.Columns(dcIndex).Column) ' Return (column)
    
    If DEBUG_PRINT Then
        Debug.Print dmrg.Address(0, 0), dlrg.Address(0, 0), drrg.Address(0, 0)
    End If
    
    ' Clear the destination data range when 1st month (January) of a new year.
    If dcIndex = 1 Then
        Intersect(dmrg.EntireColumn, dlrg.EntireRow).ClearContents
    End If

    ' Write result.
    
    Dim dCell As Range, srIndex As Variant, dr As Long
    
    For Each dCell In dlrg.Cells
        dr = dr + 1
        srIndex = Application.Match(CStr(dCell.Value), slrg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(srIndex) Then ' name found
            drrg.Cells(dr).Value = srrg.Cells(srIndex).Value
        Else ' name not found
            drrg.Cells(dr).Value = NAME_NOT_FOUND
        End If
        If DEBUG_PRINT Then
            Debug.Print dr, srIndex, drrg.Cells(dr).Value
        End If
    Next dCell
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Score card updated.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```

**Debug.Print Result**

```
August        B6:B11        J6:J11
B3:M3         A4:A10        I4:I10
 1             4             76 
 2            Error 2042    Not found
 3             1             100 
 4             2             95 
 5             3             88 
 6            Error 2042    Not found
 7             6             75
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Awesome job!